# Doubly Linked List insertion before given element

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to learn how to correctly work with pointers in C. Currently, I am trying to create function that would insert new node before the one, which value is given. My function looks like this:

```
struct list *listAddBefore(struct list *element, int insertWhat, int insertBefore)
{
    element = listToFirst(element);

    while (element -> next)
    {
        if (element -> value == insertBefore)
        {
            struct list *temp = listCreateElement(insertWhat, element->prev, element);

            element -> prev -> next = temp;
            element -> prev = temp;

            return temp;
        }
        element = element -> next;
    }

    return NULL;
}
struct list *listToFirst(struct list *element)
{
    while (element -> prev)
        element = element -> prev;

    return element;
}


struct list *listCreateElement(int value, struct list *prev, struct list *next)
{
    struct list *element = (struct list *) malloc(sizeof(struct list));

element -> value = value;
element -> prev = prev;
element -> next = next;
return element;
}
```

What is the problem? Compiler gives me segmentation error.

Comment: Run it with your debugger. It will tell you where it segfaults.

Comment: ...and show the definition of `struct list`

Comment: Here: `element -> prev -> next = temp;`, `element->prev` could be null if `element` is first in list

Comment: All your functions would fail if `element` is null (what if the list is empty?)

Comment: Yet another linked-list question with no aparrent debugging done:(

Comment: Do you REALLY mean your COMPILER is giving a segmentation error, or do you mean your "compiled executable" is giving a segmentation error when it is run?

Comment: *"I am trying to learn how to correctly work with pointers in C."* Lesson 1: check for valid pointer before dereferencing.

Comment: Also the `while (element -> next)` probably should be simply `while (element)` otherwise you will never be able to insert before the last element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code has one important problem

   ```
   while (element->next)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   while (element)
   ```

   since for the first element `element->next = NULL` and hence your function will return `NULL` immediately. Then you will pass again the head element and repeat that behavior on every call to this function.
2. Here

   ```
   element->prev->next = temp;
   ```

   you will dereference `element->prev` which must be `NULL` for the first node, you must check if it is valid or not, otherwise you will cause a [segmentation fault](https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Segmentation_fault.html). This is the correct way to link the nodes though.

I fixed your code to help you learn how to work with linked lists

```c
struct list *listToFirst(struct list *element)
{
    if (element == NULL) /* check before dereferencing */
        return NULL;
    while (element->previous != NULL)
        element = element->previous;
    return element;
}


struct list *listCreateElement(int value, struct list *prev, struct list *next)
{
    struct list *element = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    if (element == NULL) /* check the return value of malloc before dereference */
        return NULL;
    element->value = value;
    element->previous = prev;
    element->next = next;
    /*
     * here we test if there is a previous node, if there is one
     * we relink the node to point to element as it's next node.
     */
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = element;
    return element;
}

struct list *listAddBefore(struct list *element, int insertWhat, int insertBefore)
{
    element = listToFirst(element);
    while (element != NULL) /* here is the most important fix */
    {
        if (element->value == insertBefore)
            return listCreateElement(insertWhat, element->previous, element);
        /* 
         * Since the listCreateElement function takes care of linking the nodes
         * this is all we have to do here.
         *
         * note: Doing the linking in the listCreateElement, makes it more clear.
         */

        element = element->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* you should also add a free function, since you allocated the structs using malloc */
void freeList(struct list *list)
{
    struct list *current;

    current = list;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        struct list *next;

        next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct list *element;

    element = listCreateElement(0, NULL, NULL);
    element = listAddBefore(element, 1, 0);
    element = listAddBefore(element, 2, 1);
    element = listAddBefore(element, 3, 2);

    /* do something with the list */

    /* free the allocated memory */
    freeList(element);
    return 0;
}
```